# Htaccess for redirecting a directory to a file with the same name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, directory

After doing a quick lookup on how to manage sites with multiple language support, I find *site.com/language/page/* the neatest url layout. (as I don't have the funds for *site.language*)

I have used htaccess to redirect the base site from site.com to site.com/language/
by using: `RedirectMatch ^/$ /language/` where 'language' is `language.html`

But since I have a directory called /language/ so that all other pages in the given language can be put inside it, the site just shows up as the index of the directory.

How can I accomplish that kind of layout, if I want the main index page to show up in the url as site.com/language/ ?

Current htaccess that worked fine until I added the directory:

```
## Rewrite Defaults
RewriteEngine On

## Remove file extension + force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ [R=301,L]

## Redirect to /en-gb
RedirectMatch ^/$ /en-gb/
```

With the root folder looking like:

```
/language
  stuff.html
  morestuff.html
language.html
...
```

I would really appreciate help as this is currently a nightmare situation. When I try compiling the htaccess with answers to similar questions, everyone has just parts of what I am looking to achieve and thus I break the layout with every modification...

Is it possible to change the back-end filenames and accomplish this layout using only htaccess for front-end url rewriting since the url bar is the only thing that matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to solve this by removing the line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I'm afraid that this still results in the site loading as the index of the directory, and if I add a filename behind the url, it results in:
site.com/home/ftpusername/siterootdir/language/filename

Comment: I reorganised my directory to fit and it does work to some extent now, so thanks a bunch for that.

Comment: Glad you got it working to some extent. Perhaps you could open another question with your new setup and problems?

Comment: Sure, I will do that. Thank you